# Steam + Call of Duty 4 problem

Tags: steam, call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I just download Call of Duty 4 from Steam and every time I open up the multiplayer I get the following message:

> Your computer appears to have changed since the last time you ran Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare.  Would you like the game to configure itself optimally for your new hardware?

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Mine would always do that. I ended up just always hitting 'no' and it ran fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that the game is trying to save your configuration settings and failing.  Try checking whether or not the files in your CoD4 directory are write protected or not.  By default, Steam installs CoD4 to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\call of duty 4

But, this may vary depending on your Windows version, 32/64 bit, how you installed Steam, etc.

You will want to at least check all of the .cfg files, although [one person](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1333867) had better luck making sure that all of the files in that directory are not write protected.

Some people speculate this is an issue with file permissions caused by the filesystem changes in Vista/Win7, although others have reported issues with Windows XP as well.

For reference, there's a help thread on the [Activision site](http://activision.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/activision.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=16921&p_created=1156173633) for this, but I doubt that the suggestions there would help.

Comment: I changed the .cfg permission files to full access and the message never came up!  Thanks for the help. :)